# Directions Reduction problem from CodeWar

Tags: c#, algorithm, arraylist

I am tring to solve the directions reduction problem from CodeWar. The problem can be found in the following link https://www.codewars.com/kata/550f22f4d758534c1100025a/train/csharp. In this problem you get an array with strings and every string is a direction and you need to remove needless effort directions for example

```
a = {"NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH"}
```

the answer to this example will be

```
answer = {"NORTH"}
```

since north and south can be reduced and east and west too.

The solution I tried was by adding all the array elements to a list and remove items with condition. The code is working with some arrays but not all of them. In addition when I try to test the code in the VS(Visual Studio) I get a System.String[] as an output. Here is my code and thank you in advance for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class Kata
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string[] arr = { "NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST" };
            List<string> arr1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> arr2 = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            { arr1.Add(arr[i]); }
            for (int c = 0; c < arr1.Count -1; c++)
            {
                if (arr1[c] == "NORTH" && arr1[c + 1] == "SOUTH")
                {
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                }
                else if (arr1[c] == "SOUTH" && arr1[c + 1] == "NORTH")
                {
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                }
                else if (arr1[c] == "WEST" && arr1[c + 1] == "EAST")
                {
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                }
                else if (arr1[c] == "EAST" && arr1[c + 1] == "WEST")
                {
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                    arr1.Remove(arr1[c]);
                }
            }
            string[] a = arr1.ToArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            { arr2.Add(a[j]); }
            for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (arr2[i] == "NORTH" && arr2[i + 1] == "SOUTH")
                {
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                }
                else if (arr2[i] == "SOUTH" && arr2[i + 1] == "NORTH")
                {
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                }
                else if (arr2[i] == "WEST" && arr2[i + 1] == "EAST")
                {
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                }
                else if (arr2[i] == "EAST" && arr2[i + 1] == "WEST")
                {
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                    arr2.Remove(arr2[i]);
                }
            }

            string[] b = arr2.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what cases this code is not working? Did you debug your code?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(b);` will nto display the array elements. . you need to use loop to iterate thru the array and display each element one by one. or use `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", b));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a *linked list*. We take `direction` after `direction` and either add it ti the `result`
if its not oppostite to the last direction of the `result` or drop the last result direction.

For instance:

```
given  : {"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"}
result : empty

step : direction : result before : action : result after
---------------------------------------------------------
   1 : NORTH     : empty         : add    : NORTH 
   2 : SOUTH     : NORTH         : drop   : empty  
   3 : SOUTH     : empty         : add    : SOUTH   
   4 : EAST      : SOUTH         : add    : SOUTH -> EAST 
   5 : WEST      : SOUTH -> EAST : drop   : SOUTH
   6 : NORTH     : NORTH         : drop   : empty 
   7 : WEST      : WEST          : add    : WEST

Finally we have result with one item "WEST"
```

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

// The "dirReduc" name is taken from the problem template
private static string[] dirReduc(string[] path) {
  if (path == null)
    return path;

   var opposites = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
     { "North", "South" },
     { "South", "North" },
     { "East",  "West"  },
     { "West",  "East"  },
   };

   var result = new LinkedList<string>();

   foreach (string direction in path) 
     if (!string.Equals(result.Last?.Value, 
                        opposites[direction],
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       result.AddLast(direction);
     else
       result.RemoveLast();
      
   return result.ToArray();
}
```

I hope that the code is quite clear; the only trick is in `result.Last?.Value` fragment: if `result` is empty, `result.Last` will be `null` and that's why I used null propagation - `result.Last?.Value` to have `null` and not exception.

**Demo:**

```
string[] test = new string[] { 
  "NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST" };

var result = dirReduc(test);

Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

**Output:**

```
WEST
```